# Where are panel launchers located?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, launcher, 8.04

I am moving from Ubuntu 8.04 to 10.4 (yeah... :)) and I would like to copy quite a few useful launchers I created over the years.

Where are they located in 8.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after some snooping I think that I found the answer (a hidden directory):

```
$HOME/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers
```

**Update**: The above path was only half of the answer. Thanks to @DoR's reply [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20326/why-dont-8-04-panel-launchers-work-on-10-04), it seems that panel launchers also need to register at:

```
$HOME/.gconf/apps/panel/objects/
```