# Why don't 8.04 panel launchers work on 10.04

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel, launcher, 8.04

I copied my panel launchers verbatim from 8.04 to 10.04, residing in both systems in the same path:

```
$HOME/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers
```

However, for some reason, they are not visible on 10.04's GNOME panel.

Why?

**Update 1**: In my attempts to troubleshoot the problem I:

1. Verified that copied 8.04 launchers
   have same permissions as manually
   created 10.04 launchers (-rwxr-xr-x).
2. Added the first line as:
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
3. Logged off, then logged on.
4. Rebooted.

**Update 2**: I manually created a new launcher which would duplicate the functionality of a copied one. This one of course shows up and so I went ahead and compared the two, step-by-step bringing them to being **identical**! (copied icon paths, then removed the 'Encoding=UTF-8' line, etc.).

None of the above helped. So the question remains: Why?

Is there some type of "registry" out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The launchers are registered in subfolders of `/apps/panel/objects` in the [GConf settings database](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GConfEditor):

[image: Configuration Editor showing gnome-terminal launcher registration]

To backup all your panel launchers, you will need to copy both the launchers and their registrations:

1. launchers: `$HOME/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers/`
2. registrations: `$HOME/.gconf/apps/panel/objects/`